# Order string_agg over partition | BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here's the piece of my query in question:

```
string_agg(product_type, "|" order by product_type desc) over(partition by email, processed_date) as full_basket
```

I'm having issues with ordering my string_agg. The problem is that one "basket" is showing "product_a | product_b" and another may be showing "product_b | product_a", which is the same exact thing.

When I run this query, BigQuery gives me the following error: "ORDER BY in arguments is not supported on analytic functions at [14:1]"

any ideas on how to order?

Comment: I don't understand, you have `order by` in the `string_agg()` so the ordering should be consistent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'm realizing now that I didn't mention the error that is being thrown out by BigQuery. Added to the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BQ Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) specifically says that `OVER` clauses (aka analytic functions) is incompatible with other clauses within `STRING_AGG()`.

I think your best bet is to order before the aggregation.  Use CTEs to organize and order your data, then apply `STRING_AGG()` at the end.